# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless connection problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

I've recently moved and connected to the WiFi of my neighbor, who agreed to share. After a while internet connection disappeared despite WiFi is signed as connected. At the same time internet on my android devices works well. Unfortunately I cannot have access to the wire so I am writing this question from my tablet. I've already tried different solutions from this website without any success.

I would appreciate any help, but, please keep in mind that I am a complete noob and I have no opportunity to install something on the laptop from the net.

Laptop model: ThinkPad L420, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thank you in advance,
Serj

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to restart your laptop? If you have and it was not solved, then try one of these:

1. Open terminal and type in: `sudo servive network-manager restart`.
2. Go to System Setting -> Network -> Forget your neighbor's wifi and reconnect to it.

Comment: First didnt work. After fogeting, when I try to connect it shows: (32) connection could not be found.

Comment: After reboot I could connect, but the same problem again appears (signed as connected, but no internet

Comment: Try to type in terminal: `sudo ifconfig -a` to see if it has ip address. If it has, continue typing in terminal `sudo ping 8.8.8.8` to see if network is reachable.

Comment: Ifconfig gave a long. In system settings -> network -> network of my neighbor ip is given. ping gives: PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data and nothing more

Comment: *i can see ip with ifconfig

Comment: Is your Android device still works well? If it is, turn off your Android's wifi and change your laptop's MAC address to your Android's by typing this command in terminal: I assume your wifi interface is `wlan0` so type: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`  to bring down your network interface. Then type `sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether <Androi's MAC>`. Afterward, `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to bring up interface.  Finally, `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Does your laptop have other OS such as Windows. Is it work well on Windows?

Comment: No. Ubuntu is the only one

Comment: When your laptop has wired connection, try to  reinstall network-manager. So weird, network is reachable, but dont have internet access. You can tell your neighbor restart him/her's modem.

Comment: So right now there is nothing I can do? What is the procedure to reinstall network manager?

Comment: I just edited my comment above. To reinstall network-manager, you must have wired connection. Then type: `sudo apt-get remove network-manager` to uninstall it and `sudo apt-get install network-manager`.

Comment: Ok, many thanks, could I just ask how did you deduce that the network is reachable?

Comment: You say in above comment that `sudo ping 8.8.8.8` have signal. That's mean network is reachable. It should look like this: `PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=72.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=77.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=78.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=44 time=72.8 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 72.377/75.220/78.154/2.650 ms
`

Comment: Ping says: 6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% loss, time 5039ms

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give you the ping statistics above and it was misleading

Comment: Oh man! That means your network is too slow or something. Is your wifi signal strength? You can type in: `sudo iw wlan0 scan` to check.

Comment: Strenght is good.  The command gives huge output. What should I look for in it?

Comment: If wifi signal is strong enough, I think restart router is worth a shot.

Comment: Restart DID work. I have the internet now. I feel so stupid now. What could be the reason?? Many, many thanks to you anyway.